# Using Powershell to list the Administrators of a AD Group

Tags: powershell

I am new to Powershell Scripting and need some advice/pointers.  I am trying to write a script that will list the "Administrator(s)" of an AD Group.  Has anyone had experience with this? Any examples or links would be extremely helpful.

Comment: `I am trying to write a script that will list the "Administrator(s)" of an AD Group` - What do you mean the Administrators of a group?

Comment: Users at my employer can request the creation of AD Groups based on work requirements.  The requestor then adds users to the AD group, and can also add users as administrators of the group.  I need to pull out the users who have AD Group Admin privileges.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you're talking about AD Group manager and checkbox "Manager can update membership list". This checkbox modifies group DACL and grants write members attribute privilege.

Simple answer. Use the value set in AD object attribute. This gives you just a name in the attribute (as shown in ADUC).

```
Get-ADObject -Identity (Get-ADGroup -Identity "Group Name" -Properties managedby).managedby
```

Hard answer. Query AD object DACL for WriteProperty to members attribute. This does not include WriteAllProperty or Full privileges! With the example it shouldn't be hard to filter out these but they're likely default system DACL entries.

```
$Group = Get-ADGroup -Identity "Group Name"
$ACL = Get-Acl -Path ('AD:' + $Group.distinguishedName)
$Access = $ACL.Access
#"bf9679c0-0de6-11d0-a285-00aa003049e2" is GUID for object property "members"
$GroupAdmins = $Access | Where-Object -FilterScript {$_.ObjectType -eq "bf9679c0-0de6-11d0-a285-00aa003049e2" -and  $_.ActiveDirectoryRights -eq "WriteProperty"}
$Groupadmins.IdentityReference| ForEach-Object {Get-ADUser -Identity $_.translate([System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier]).Value}
```

Comment: Thanks!  Any way to get the Username/ User display name Instead of the IdentityRefereence?  I tried modifying the last line of the script but only got a blank table.

Comment: I improved my answer (last line), it should now give each user's object for easy further filtering.